# I want to change some of the linux files, how to recompile the linux and reinstall it

Tags: kernel, compiling

I want to make changes to the kernel files /linux/net/ipv4/ip_output.c in my case. I want to add a script to be run that changes the payload of the data whenever a packet passes through the IP_LOCAL_OUTPUT hook. Now when I add that script, how do I recompile the kernel that make the changes operable.

Comment: This guide may help you: https://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/305766-recompile-your-kernel-for-a-perfect-fit

Comment: I'll look into it and report back, Thanx

Comment: I get this error when i do make oldcofig while i am in the directory where source code is present, its linux-3.9 in my case. What can be the problem?

Makefile:497: /home/ip-center/linux-3.9/arch//Makefile: No such file or directory
make: *** No rule to make target `/home/ip-center/linux-3.9/arch//Makefile'.  Stop.

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu and Debian have thier own way to rebuild kernel. Methods from other distros DO NOT apply. [Here is the right procedure](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/BuildYourOwnKernel), follow the `apt-src` way.

Comment: P.S. If you remove modules from menuconfig while using this way, it will not compile. I believe there is a config line for this case.

Comment: When shall i make changes to the files i want as i mentioned in linux/net/ipv4/ip_output.c file? Shall I change it after the first step of getting the source code using apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r). and then go ahead with next steps? Sorry if this is a silly question to ask

Comment: Yes, exactly this moment, before you run menuconfig.